# Is is possible to put my MBP’s old DDR3 RAM into my GF’s DDR2 MacBook?

Tags: memory, macbook, macbook-pro, ddr3, ddr2

I have 4GB of 1067MHz DDR3 RAM, upgrading to 8GB, in my late-2008 Apple MacBook Pro.

Crucial’s scanner says my girlfriend’s slightly older MacBook can support 4GB of 500-something-MHz DDR2 RAM (she has 2GB now).

Is it a really, really terrible idea to put my RAM into her computer?

Comment: (To be clear, I assume it would run at a slower speed, if at all.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Don't do it

DDR3 and DDR2 are not at all compatible. Different number of pins, different technology, completely different. It won't even fit in the slot properly. Bad idea.